# I'm trying to set up a custom trigger for Alexa Routines. To do this one of the steps is to update the manifest to add the "routines" api

Tags: manifest, alexa-interaction-model

I am able to update the manifest with some new permissions but when I add the "routines" api as shown in the example I get a 400 error with not much information. Am I not able to update the manifest because I am not registered to use custom triggers perhaps? Is anybody else trying to use custom triggers?

I tried to update the manifest and see the routine on the DevCon. I got the 400 error and it doesn't update.

Answer (score 2):

Can you make sure if you are onboarded from https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/blogs/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/2023/09/custom-triggers-routines-alexa-september-2023. You can also get support to email to Amazon on https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/routines/get-started-custom-triggers-for-routines.html